# How can I write a sql query to check if a particular table exists in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to use queries but I've never had to use one for this particular tasks .. I know about the SHOW TABLES; command .. How can I write a query to check if a particular table exists in a MYSQL database .. For example , a query that checks if table MEMBERS exists in database called USERS ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html)

```
USE USERS;
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MEMBERS'
```

Answer (score 2):

Searching Table:

`select * from
information_schema.tables
where table_name like '%MEMBERS%'`

Searching Column:

`select * from
information_schema.columns
where table_name like '%COLUMN%'`